# input type radio vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

how to align vertically these two radio buttons
they should be aligned by `x` axes

```css
.wrap{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:auto auto;
background:orange;
}

input[type='radio']{
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0 9px;
 line-height:25px;
 vertical-align:middle;
}

.bbtn{
 display:inline-block;
 line-height:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div>
<input type='radio' name='aradio' value='a' checked>
</div>
<div>
<input type='radio' name='aradio' value='b'>
<div class='bbtn'>LOREM</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to explain better what you mean by *they should be aligned by `x` axes*

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava - so `x` axis is a horizontal axis. what else is needed to explain?

Comment: The output of your code in question is also in horizontal axis. So what is your question?

Comment: he's asking only for **how( not why**), do you have the answer? @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: It is unclear to me as a question, so no I do not have an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the text is playing a role in defining the alignment make sure you will always have at least a similar thing like an empty pseudo element with the same properties:

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background: orange;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  margin: 0 9px;
  /*vertical-align: middle; change this to what you want to control the alignment */
}

.bbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.wrap> div::after{
  content:"";
  line-height:25px; /* the same as the one used with bbtn */
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div>
    <input type='radio' name='aradio' value='a' checked>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type='radio' name='aradio' value='b'>
    <div class='bbtn'>LOREM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems like a hacking solution. if there is no a normal way... - unbelievable

Comment: @qadenza it's not hacky, you are dealing with different container so there is no relation between both. If you want to have the same alignment, you will need to have the same condition in both.

Comment: `you are dealing with different container` - pls explain - first radio is radio and second radio is radio - so the same element. first parent is a div and the second parent is a div - so the same container.

Comment: @qadenza the same type of parent but not the same parent. You have 2 Divs so two *different* container and each input inside a container. So both aren't in the same world and in one of the container we have text which make both container different (we don't have the same condition). The text is affecting the alignment so you cannot say that both are in the same conditions that's why I added an empty pseudo element to make sure we have the same conditions

Answer (score 0):

This CodePen shows them aligned vertically on the left hand side. Is this what you are after? I changed `grid-template-columns: auto auto;` to `grid-template-columns: 1fr;`

https://codepen.io/gunderodd/pen/abOGzpO

Comment: they should be aligned by `x` and not by `y` axes

Comment: How about adding ```text-align: center;``` to the ```.wrap``` class?

Comment: More importantly, did you try?

Comment: there is no need to try for me, it's clear it doesn't work